# Sandbox service permissions required to activate a solution on an RBS enabled database

Tags: 2013, sandbox-solution, rbs

We have a Remote Blob Storage (RBS) enabled database. When trying to activate the CRMListComponent sandbox solution, an error occured:

> UserCodeExecutionProxy call pipeline failed with execution.
>   ServiceUrl: tcp:////SPUCExecutionHost;
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeExecutionPipelineFailedException:
>   Unable to load assembly group. The user assembly group provider threw
>   an exception while trying to provide user assemblies for the specified
>   assembly group.

We were able to activate the sandbox solution after granting the "**db_rbs_admin**" database role to the sandbox service account.

Since this confirms its a permission issue, my question is:

**What is the least amount of privilege** required for the service account? We don't want to give more permission than necessary.

The only mention I see in SharePoint RBS documentation is that the SharePoint IIS application pool identity that runs the website hosting the content DB needs "**db_owner**" privileges on the content db, but no mentions of any other service application or service identities.